# Join not updating values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables, one with insurance-claim data and another with insurance policy data. and I want to join both table on  policy_no column to retrieve policy details of the claims.

query:

```
UPDATE claims a
       LEFT JOIN premium b
              ON a.claim_num = b.claim_no
SET    a.policy_no = b.policy_no;
```

The output for this comes as 0 rows updated. there has to be at least 60% matching data for this to happen. there are values in policy_no from premium but gives null on claims policy_no

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: Could it be that claim_num/claim_no have different data types and they don't match? You didn't tell us about the data types and you didn't show example data that would match

Answer (score 0):

You should try a proper way like this
Let me know if I don’t understood your question

```
update a
Set a.policy_no = b.policy_no
From
claims a left join premium b on a.claim_num = b.claim_no
```